# How to convert points to pixels to scale properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math, pixel

I'm trying to do and image highlight. So I take pdf image preview and based on the field (extracted from pdf) the user clicks, it will highlight the field in the image preview.

Im trying to accomplish this using css where a have rectangle at the bottom of the image and just set a margin based on the field position that will highlight that field in the pdf image preview.

The problem is that I can't quite get the conversion right for my margins.

So I know there 72pt in an inch and 96 pixels in an inch.

Don't really know where to take it form there. Should I also consider the user's resolution? Is there a library I can use?

So far what I have given:
field positions (in points), 
pdf max height/width (in points), 
image preview max height/width (in pixels)

How can I convert the field position to pixels so I can highlight that field in the image preview?

Answer (score 1):

Convert points to pixels.

1. pdfPointsH / pdfPixelsH = x
2. pdfPointsW / pdfPixelsW = y
3. Use proportion to translate Point coordinates into Pixel coordinates e.g.:

PointX * x = PixelX

PointY * y = PixelY

Hope that helps.

Comment: how will we get the height and width in points in javascript?